# How to bind a function to Click event of each control in an array of controls in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, bind, control-array

When you create an array of controls in C#, how can you bind a function that receives the index of the clicked button to their click event?

Here's some code solely for better understanding. Somewhere on top of the code you define the buttons:

```
Button [] buttons = new Button[100];
```

The standard Click event of them looks like this:

```
private void myClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

And normally you bind it this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    buttons[i].Click += myClick;
```

**But I want the event handler to be in this form:**

```
private void myClick(int Index)
{

}
```

How should I bind click events to the above function with / without interim functions?

I thought about using delegates, `Func<T, TResult>` notation, or somehow pass a custom EventArgs which contains the Index of the clicked button; but I wasn't successful due to lack of enough C# knowledge.

If any of you are going to suggest saving the index of each control in its Tag: Yes it was possible but I don't wanna use it for some reason, since if you have a class which throws some events but doesn't have a Tag property or something, this way is useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int index = i;    
buttons[index].Click += (sender, e) => myClick(index);
```

As posted in the comment below, using 'i' will use the same variable for all controls due to it's scope. It's therefore necessary to create a new variable in the same scope as the lambda expression.

Comment: In a for loop, i had to write `var index=i; buttons[i].Click += (sender, e) => myClick(index);` See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6439477/

Answer (score 2):

```
private void myClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = buttons.IndexOf(sender as Button);
}
```

Comment: This requires buttons to be a field, and linear search in the buttons array

Comment: I'am aware of that, and I voted up your answer, because I like them. But at all, I would not miss the `EventArgs` in a handler. May be on further development, its required to interact with them.