# Lambda expression not working in setting the event-handler of some controls

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, lambda

I'm creating an array of controls and adding them to the form, and setting their events to a function that receives the index of the clicked button using a lambda expression (`b.Click += (sender, e) => myClick(i);`).

But the problem is... Whichever you click on, you receive the index 100, not the real index of the button! What is the problem here?

```
namespace testArrayOfControls
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button[] buttons;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            buttons = new Button[100];
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                buttons[i] = new Button();
                buttons[i].SetBounds(i % 10 * 50, i / 10 * 50, 50, 50);
                buttons[i].Click += (sender, e) => myClick(i);
                this.Controls.Add(buttons[i]);
            }
        }

        private void myClick(int i)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: read my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095707/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-a-closure/1095770#1095770

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you create closure over the loop variable `i`. You need to make a local (inside the `for` loop) copy of it before passing it to the event handler.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var index = i; // YOU NEED TO DO THIS
    buttons[i] = new Button();
    buttons[i].SetBounds(i % 10 * 50, i / 10 * 50, 50, 50);
    buttons[i].Click += (sender, e) => myClick(index); // THIS SOLVES THE PROBLEM
    this.Controls.Add(buttons[i]);
}
```

**Explanation**

You are defining a function like this:

```
(sender, e) => myClick(i)
```

This function (which will run at some point in the future, when the button is clicked) includes a reference to `i`. The way, this works is that it will use the value of `i` *at the time when the click occurs*, not at the time the function is defined.

By that time, clearly the value of `i` will have become 100.

The solution works because it makes the function take a reference to the variable `index` instead of `i`. `index` differs from `i` in that `i` is one variable whose value changes, while `index` is a name we use for 100 different variables (one for each loop iteration), *the value of which remains constant*.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is to do with *modified closures*. [Here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/csharp2/delegates.html#captured.variables) is an excellent explanation of the subject by @Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = i; 
buttons[i].Click += (sender, e) => myClick(index);
```

Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately closures (in ur case the variable i) doesn't work the way they should be in C#.
Replace

```
b.Click += (sender, e) => myClick(i);
```

with

```
Action<int,Button> act = (index,b) => { b.click += (sender, e) => myClick(index) }
act(i,b);
```